# Getting error after upgrading ProductService.Host into 4.3 and .net 5

Tags: c#, module, microservices, upgrade, abp

I got the following error after upgrading NuGet packages in the [`ProductService.Host`](https://github.com/abpframework/abp-samples/tree/master/MicroserviceDemo/microservices/ProductService.Host) in the [`Microservice Demo`](https://github.com/abpframework/abp-samples/tree/master/MicroserviceDemo) solution into 4.3 version and .net 5:

> An error occurred while accessing the `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting` services. Continuing without the application service provider. Error: Could not load type 'Volo.Abp.Authorization.IAbpAuthorizationPolicyProvider' from assembly 'Volo.Abp.Authorization, Version=4.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

Try `Add-Migration "Upgrade"` in the NuGet console or run and see the log file.
**P.S:** I didn't get this error in the `BloggingService.Host` project.

Comment: delete all bin & obj folders